# Java convert excel-base64 string to pdf-base64 string

Tags: javascript, java, excel, pdf

I consume api which return as excel base64 string, but I want to convert it to pdf base64 string instead as I need to download in PDF in Javascript. Is it posible to do so?

Comment: [What's the difference between JavaScript and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245062/whats-the-difference-between-javascript-and-java)

Comment: I meant I want to convert base64 in excel to base64 in pdf.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to either write some very heavy code to convert a b64 zip file to a b64 pdf archive then you can sell that at any price.

The alternatives are

Convert XLSfile.B64 to file.xlsx convert file.xlsx to file.pdf then convert file.pdf to PDFfile.B64

Or use a Java based API suite to do similar.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I may user the select alternative.